# Check in ansible if value is lower with islower

Tags: ansible

Could someone give an example to check if the value of a variable is lowercase with islower?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the islower function:

```
- name: echo test
  debug:
    msg: |
      is low lower?: {{ low.islower() }} 
      is notlow lower?: {{ notlow.islower() }}
  vars:
    low: er
    notlow: Er
```